# How can I disable the Complete account setup prompt in Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, google-settings

Every now and then when I want to install an app from the Play Store, Google has to remind me that I haven't finished setting up my account, at which point I can only press '*Continue*', to be met with a payment option selection box:

[image]
<sup>Image taken from googleapis.com</sup>

I don't want to needlessly tie another account to my Google profile.
I know I can '*Skip*' from that point onward, but it's uselessly annoying. Is there any way to disable this prompt (that is: to let Google know that whenever I want to buy something I'll find my way myself)?

Comment: The only way I know is to buy and redeem a gift code so that your account has some money on it. The lowest amount seems to be a 10 USD code e.g. bought via PayPal. Adding a credit card would also work of course. I am still looking into testing what happens if you add a credit card that expires some days later...

Comment: @Robert, good idea. And on that note, adding a bogus PayPal account might also work..

Answer (score -1):

Is the sign always popping up or does it not appear again when u skip once?

Other, just make a paypal acc and link it without actually purchasing anything. If I recall correctly u dont even need a credit card